# How do I concatenate two similar tables on a result

Tags: sql

I have two tables with similar columns. I would simply like to select both tables, one after another, so that if I have 'x' rows on table1 and 'y' rows on table2, I'd get 'x + y' rows.

Comment: If there are duplicates, do you want them removed or left in place?  It matters, because `UNION` removes duplicates--`UNION ALL` doesn't, and is faster for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use `UNION [ALL]` for this. The tables don't need to have the same column names but you do need to select the same number of columns from each and the corresponding columns need to be of compatible datatypes

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM table2
```

`UNION ALL` is preferrable to `UNION` where there is a choice as it can avoid a sort operation to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: his tables were clearly name table1 and table2, while x and y were used as row counts.  i find this answer unacceptable... ;)

Comment: @nathan - I'll remedy this just to please you! Edit: Done.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to what they were saying, you might want to add an Order By.  Depends on the version of SQL you're using.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM   Table1
UNION
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM   Table2
ORDER BY Col1
```

Note that ORDER and GROUP BYs have to go after the last table in the UNION.

Answer (score 2):

```
select col1,col2,col3 from table1
union
select col1,col2,col3 from table2
```

Comment: The OP wants all rows, therefore `UNION ALL`. A `UNION` will eliminate duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Union](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator.